# Is it possible to "remote" refine?

Tags: eve-online

Is it possible in any way to refine ore remotely?

Suppose I had 300k veldspar that I wanted to refine to make a courier contract, but I wasn't in the system. What's the easiest way to turn the veldspar into trit without flying there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's impossible within Eve Online right now. There is no skill that would allow you to refine or reprocess elements in a remote location, just as you can't ---------- accept mission. Remote action are strictly controlled in Eve to avoid hack/exploit, especially concerning low/high security interaction I guess.

The way to easy the process would be the Jump clone but I guess this is not an efficient way.

Comment: Except that you can sell remotely, via the Marketing skill (Trade category).

Comment: Ty, I didn't know. I edited my post so it's now correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the skill "Marketing", which allows you to remote sell within a certain range or full regional on level 5, remote sell it.

If you don't have this skill, sell it via contracts.

Then buy Tritanium from the profits on the Station you are.

That is the easiest way.